# NodeJs seems to interrupt funciton without error

Tags: node.js, promise

I've got a node.js function that behaves in a way I can't explain. It seems to just stop in the middle and neither succeed nor fail.

I'm an old hand at coding, but rather new to node.js, so I'd be grateful if somebody could explain to me what's going on here.

My understanding is that if one awaits a promise, one sooner or later either gets a return value (even if it's undefined) or an error is thrown if the promise fails.

I've also tried attaching a .then and a .catch to the promise, with exactly the same result.

As far as my understanding goes, this behaviour shoud not be possible, at least one of the `console.log` after the invocation should trigger one way or another.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    myFunction();

}

const myFunction = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('This triggers 100 times');
        var response = await problematicFunctionSupposedToReturnPromise();
        console.log(response, 'This never triggers');

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err,'This never triggers either');
    }
    console.log('Nor does this');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be rather related to the way you have implemented that `problematicFunctionSupposedToReturnPromise`, because this is working fine with node :

```js
function problematicFunctionSupposedToReturnPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    resolve("ok!")
  })
}

const myFunction = async () => {
  console.log('Try promise');
  var response = await problematicFunctionSupposedToReturnPromise()
    .catch(err => console("oops"));
  console.log('Got response', response);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  myFunction();

}


console.log("will call promises")
```

1. The `Try promise` will be printed a 100 times all together when each promise is stacked one after another, before being executed. Only `myFunction` is executed a 100 times at this moment.
2. When the end of synchronous scope is reached, the `"will call promises"` is printed
3. The 100 promises are unstacked and the 100 `"got response", "ok"` are printed.

You may also obtain a more "synchronous" workflow is you await `myFunction`

```js
async function promises() {
  function problematicFunctionSupposedToReturnPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
      resolve("ok!")
    })
  }

  const myFunction = async () => {
    console.log('Try promise');
    var response = await problematicFunctionSupposedToReturnPromise()
      .catch(err => console("oops"));
    console.log('Got response', response);
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    await myFunction();

  }
}

promises()
```

Comment: So you are saying my misconception lies in the way I assume "await" works? From your explanations I understand it doesn't pause execution of the entire code until the promise resolves, it just pauses the execution of the function it is in, is that it?

Comment: Yes, in your code, and in my first example  which behaves like yours (just changed a little the syntax), the loop doesn't wait for the promise resolution. So the logs with the responses are only executed after the loop is ended. But as I said, if your code doesn't work it might be related to another problem in the function that returns the promise, because, when I implement it with a trivial promise it actually works. (your "never called" console logs are actually called, but only after the loop)